# error blob uploading Warning: fopen(C:\xampp\tmp\php4FC4.tmp): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, javascript

i'm trying to create multiple uploading with BLOB.

The above code gives me the following error

> Warning: fopen(C:\xampp\tmp\php4FC4.tmp): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

PHP script

```
$jumlah_file = count($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
$path = pathinfo($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

for ($i = 0; $i < $jumlah_file; $i++)
{
    $tmp_file = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $filetype = $_FILES['userfile']['type'][$i];
    $filesize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'][$i];
    $filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i];
    $destination = $path['dirname'].
    '/data/'.$filename;
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$destination);
}

$fp = fopen($tmp_file, 'r'); // ERROR LINE
$content = fread($fp, filesize($tmp_file));
$content = addslashes($content);
fclose($fp);

if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
    $fileName = addslashes($filename);
}

$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `konveksi`.`foto` (`id_foto`, `id_daftar`, `id_pesanan`, `foto`) VALUES (NULL, '15', '1','$content');");
mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
```

what must I do? Please excuse me if this is stupid question, I am very new to PHP.

Comment: You already used `move_uploaded_file()` before the `fopen`. Afterwards the file is located elsewhere. -- Also `addslashes()` is not the right function for database escaping.

Comment: what right function for my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already moved the file using  `move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$destination);` before the `$fp = fopen($tmp_file, 'r');`. Afterwards the file is located elsewhere.
The correct code is :

```
$jumlah_file = count($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
$path = pathinfo($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

for ($i = 0; $i < $jumlah_file; $i++)
{
    $tmp_file = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $filetype = $_FILES['userfile']['type'][$i];
    $filesize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'][$i];
    $filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i];
    $destination = $path['dirname'].
    '/data/'.$filename;
    $fp = fopen($tmp_file, 'r');
    $content = fread($fp, filesize($tmp_file));
    $content = addslashes($content);
    fclose($fp);
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$destination);
}

if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
    $fileName = addslashes($filename);
}

$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `konveksi`.`foto` (`id_foto`, `id_daftar`, `id_pesanan`, `foto`) VALUES (NULL, '15', '1','$content');");
mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
```